# Python: Rearrange column order in DataFrame by ascending values

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame columns are:

```
df.columns
>>>Index([u'1', u'10', u'120', u'1800', u'30', u'300', u'3600', u'5', u'60', u'600'], dtype='object')
```

How I can sort my columns so that I have an ascending sequence like `1, 5, 10, 30, 60, 120, 300, 600, 1800, 3600`?
I tried this:
    df = df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)

But does not work with numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast them to ints, and then sort.

```
In [16]: idx = df.columns
In [17]: df.columns = idx.astype(int)

In [18]: idx.order()
Out[18]: Int64Index([1, 5, 10, 30, 60, 120, 300, 600, 1800, 3600], dtype='int64')
```

You'll need to set the dataframe's columns to the int version. Then call `df = df[idx.order()]`.

Comment: thanks but `.astype(int)` is applied to values in my df and not only to the columns. How can I get only my columns into `int`?

Comment: Here, `idx = df.columns`. So you don't have to change your values at all. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: `id` -> `idx`, d'you mean?

Comment: You're right DSM, thanks. Also meant to set that to the columns, not the index :)

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
df.rename(columns=int).sort(axis=1)
```

`rename` expects a function to convert by.